# To convert not null datetime into null. c#

Tags: c#, sql, database

I would like to make my not null `DateTime` column `null` when I do the sum of the entire table so that I do not get any value for date time `1/1/0001 12:00:00`. I would like to add whatever possible statement into this method. I tried to do parse it but it doesn't work, but for `Amount` it's perfectly fine.

```
private void SumOfRecords_Button(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ObservableCollection<Receipt> receipts = new ReceiptDAO().GetAllReceiptsFromPiName();
    Receipt receipt = new Receipt();

    if (receipt.DateTime != null)
    {
        Receipt receipt0 = new Receipt()
        {
            DateTime = DateTime.TryParse(),
            Amount = new ReceiptDAO().SumOfRecords("Amount")
        };

        receipts.Add(receipt);
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => ReceiptList.ItemsSource = receipts);
    }
}
```

This is the method for `SumOfRecords` where I am writing my query.

```
public double SumOfRecords(string columnName)
{
    ObservableCollection<Receipt> receipts = new ReceiptDAO().GetAllReceiptsFromPiName();
    Receipt receipt = new Receipt();
    string commandstring;
    commandstring = "select Sum(" + columnName + ") from " + getTable();
    
    using (SQLiteConnection connection = ConnectToDatabase())
    {
        using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(commandstring, connection))
        {
            using (SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                reader.Read();
                return reader.GetDouble(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's in `SumOfRecords` ?

Comment: It would be awesome to have a [mcve].

Comment: I just added what is in my SumOfRecords method.

Comment: [Why is concatenating SQL strings a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23179329/why-is-concatenating-sql-strings-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ignore dates when you calculate the sum. Assuming you're using sql server for database.

```
var where = " WHERE Table.Date <> '0001/01/01 00:00:00'";
commandstring = "select Sum(" + columnName + ") from " + getTable() + where;
```

You can pass `where` as a parameter to the method to make it reusable. Based on what database you're using, you may want look into date comparison. Otherwise the concept remains the same.