# How to use 2 conditions at a time in Visual studio using sqlDataAdapter? I need to identify a value from Dropdownlist and also sort it using DateTime

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, web-applications, sqldataadapter

```
SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(("SELECT Master_ID,Station,Job_ID,Conveyor,Andon_PC,Cast(Start_Time as time(2) )as Start_Time,Cast(Close_Time as time(2) )as Close_Time,Duration,Loss_Type,Loss_Description,Reason,Line_Name FROM Vehicle_Andon WHERE Reason IS NULL AND (Loss_Type IS NULL OR Loss_Type !=2) AND Line_Name =" + "'" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'", sqlcon) + "Cast(Date_Time as date) = " + "'" + Date1.Value + "'" + "order by Date_Time desc", sqlcon);

sqlda.Fill(dtbl);
```

Comment: Why is concatenating SQL strings a bad idea?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23179329/why-is-concatenating-sql-strings-a-bad-idea

Comment: It was just that sqlcon was not for the Dropdownlist value to be selected using SQL query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(("SELECT Master_ID,Station,Job_ID,Conveyor,Andon_PC,Cast(Start_Time as time(2) )as Start_Time,Cast(Close_Time as time(2) )as Close_Time,Duration,Loss_Type,Loss_Description,Reason,Line_Name FROM Vehicle_Andon WHERE Reason IS NULL AND (Loss_Type IS NULL OR Loss_Type !=2) AND Line_Name =" + "'" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'") + "Cast(Date_Time as date) = " + "'" + Date1.Value + "'" + "order by Date_Time desc", sqlcon);

sqlda.Fill(dtbl);
```

Comment: Hello and congrats to your first answer. Please add some Text to describe it. And maybe you can wrap your code?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).